# Is there a way to use Microsoft.UI.Xaml in a Visual Studio 2022 extension

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-extensions, winui-3

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension that has multiple async windows. I came across the NuGet package [Microsoft.UI.Xaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml/) which provides a lot of well-made custom controls that blend well with Visual Studio.

The problem is upon installation the extension supposes that you will run it in a standalone WPF application and tells you (like in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started#download-and-install-the-windows-ui-library):

> Don't forget to set XamlControlsResources as your Application
> resources in App.xaml:
>
> ```
> <Application>
>     <Application.Resources>
>         <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
>     </Application.Resources>
> </Application>
> ```
>
> If you have other resources, then we recommend you add those to the
> XamlControlsResources' MergedDictionaries. This works with the
> platform's resource system to allow overrides of the
> XamlControlsResources resources.

I used [Extensibility Essentials 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensibilityEssentials2022) to start a "VSIX Project w/Tool Window (Cummunity)" project and the project structure came as follows:

```bash
│   VSIXProject1.sln
│
└───VSIXProject1
    │   source.extension.cs
    │   source.extension.vsixmanifest
    │   VSCommandTable.cs
    │   VSCommandTable.vsct
    │   VSIXProject1.csproj
    │   VSIXProject1Package.cs
    │
    ├───Commands
    │       MyToolWindowCommand.cs
    │
    ├───Properties
    │       AssemblyInfo.cs
    │
    ├───Resources
    │       Icon.png
    │
    └───ToolWindows
            MyToolWindow.cs
            MyToolWindowControl.xaml
            MyToolWindowControl.xaml.cs
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to use the Microsoft.UI.Xaml library

Comment: One idea is to first make a package-based project into a class, and then let the VSIX package be developed based on this class.